# Can i clear value data of default value in subregistry?

Tags: vb.net, registry

I tried using this code to reasign nothing to the default value after I assigned its value = "abc", but I got an error that I couldn't assign null to the default value. Can i do this?

```
Using k As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = reg.OpenSubKey(path, True)
        'k?.SetValue(vbNullString, vbNullString)
        k.DeleteValue("")
End Using
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a silly thing, you have to specify `null` (`Nothing`) instead of an empty string (or `(Default)` or `Default`, which is what usually comes to mind until you read `RegistryKey.GetValueNames()` and it appears to be an empty string :)

```
Using k As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = reg.OpenSubKey(path, True)
    ' Set a Value
    k.SetValue(Nothing, "New Value")

    ' Or delete the current value
    k.DeleteValue(Nothing)
End Using
```

Comment: Hi, I did not know this! this works for me now! Thanks.